# tcolorbox, divided box

Tags: tcolorbox

I use `tcolorbox`. How I can achieve box like draft bellow?

```
--------------------
|Lorem   |ipsum    |
|        |         |
--------------------
|Lorem ipsum dolor |
|                  | 
--------------------
```

When I combine two boxes, I have space between them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %kolor wokół sekcji
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{FirstBox}[2]{
    sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
    skin=enhanced#2,
    boxsep=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,
    colback=black!5!white,
    colframe=black!75!white,
    title={Box {\bf #1}}
}

\newtcolorbox{SecondBox}[2]{
boxsep=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,top=0mm,
colback=black!5!white,
colframe=black!75!white,
skin=enhanced#2,
}

%--------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{FirstBox}{ABC}{first}
Lorem ipsum dolor
\tcblower
Lorem ipsum dolor
\end{FirstBox}

\begin{SecondBox}{ABC}{last}
\lipsum[4]
\end{SecondBox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can to play with `before` and `after` options trying to delete this white space but I think a better solution would be to build this construction inside a single `tcolorbox`.

The first part could be build with a `tabular` or two column environment.

But if you insist in a `side by side` `tcolorbox` you can insert a box inside another one.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %kolor wokół sekcji
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newtcolorbox{outerBox}[1]{
    breakable, enhanced,
    colback=black!5!white,
    colframe=black!75!white,
    title={Box {\bf #1}},
    top=0pt
}

\newtcolorbox{twocolBox}{
    sidebyside, sidebyside align=top,
    enhanced,
    arc=0pt,
    colback=black!5!white,
    colframe=black!75!white,
    boxsep=1mm,
    notitle,
    oversize,
    nobeforeafter,
    frame hidden,
}

%--------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{outerBox}{ABC}
\begin{twocolBox}
Lorem ipsum dolor
\tcblower
Lorem ipsum dolor
\end{twocolBox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{outerBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is one example with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{MyBox}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    boxsep=0pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    colframe=red!50!black,
    colbacktitle=red!30!white,
    coltitle=black,
    before title={\noindent},
    #1
}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{MyBox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X},title=Box ABC]%
    Lorem ipsum dolor & Lorem ipsum dolor \\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{p{0.96\linewidth}}{\lipsum*[4]}
\end{MyBox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While there are possibilities for improvement, this should serve as a starting point.

Comment: This was my initial intention but I didn't know `tabularx*`, just `tabularx` which didn't worked. I learn something new every day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there are rounded box corners there will be a slight separation at the border between two boxes at the corners.

The `tcolorbox` environment introduces top and bottom parskip values, which can be omitted by setting `nobeforeafter`, however, this indents the box a little bit. This can be prevented by using `\noindent.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %kolor wokół sekcji
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}






\newtcolorbox{FirstBox}[2]{%
    sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
    boxsep=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    colback=black!5!white,
    colframe=black!75!white,
    nobeforeafter,%
    title={Box {\textbf{#1}}},
    auto outer arc,
    arc=0mm
    skin=enhanced#2
}%

\newtcolorbox{SecondBox}[2]{
boxsep=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,
colback=black!5!white,%
colframe=black!75!white,
nobeforeafter,
toprule=0pt,
notitle,
arc=0pt,
auto outer arc,
    skin=enhanced#2
}%


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{FirstBox}{ABC}{first}
Lorem ipsum dolor
\tcblower
Lorem ipsum dolor

\end{FirstBox}
\begin{SecondBox}{ABC}{last}
\lipsum[4]
\end{SecondBox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Improved(???) version using one `\newcommand`, doing all in one:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %kolor wokół sekcji
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}



\newcommand*{\SuperBox}[6][]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!75!white,  skin=enhanced,#1,title=#2]
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,notitle,boxrule=-1pt,left=0pt,top=0pt,titlerule=0pt,leftlower=0pt,nobeforeafter,bottomtitle=-10pt,notitle]
#4%
\tcblower%
#5%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,%
nobeforeafter,%
boxrule=-1pt,%
notitle]%
#6%
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%




\begin{document}
% [opt arg]{box title}{unused skin}{left box content}{right box content}{lower box content}
\SuperBox{Box ABC}{First}{Lorem ipsum dolor left}{Lorem ipsum dolor right}{\lipsum[4]}


\SuperBox[colframe=red,colbacktitle=red,coltitle={yellow}]{Box ABC}{First}{Lorem ipsum dolor left}{Lorem ipsum dolor \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{right}}}{\lipsum[8]}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a second inner box in `SuperBox`? Inner boxes are not breakable so I think it's better to leave second box text as outer box text written after first inner box as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Ignasi: I initially thought about a tabular approach, leaving two separate boxes, but I had not enough time, switched to my first (not really good) solution. The second solution is rather 'fun'. You are right: The inner box is not breakable, but that is a feature not explicitly demanded, is it?